# Android dev: updating ui textview using runOnUiThread, crashes

Tags: android, user-interface, textview

My goal is when the user tap start button, letters "o" "n" "o" "m" and so forth will appear at the center of the screen. "o" will appear first then after a few seconds will be replaced by "n" then "o" and so forth.

note: for brevity, i just make the guessword = onomatopoeia, first. In reality, guessword will changes every time i tap the start bottom.

this is the code:

As was suggested, I implemented runonuithread but it still crashes:

```
public class PlayActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private String guessword = "onomatopoeia";
private TextView showchar;
private int n = guessword.length();
private char letArray[]= guessword.toCharArray();
private Handler handler;
private int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play); 
    handler = new Handler();
    showchar = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.charView);
}

public void startGame(View view){
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while(i++ < n) {
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                             showchar.setText(letArray[i]);
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();

}
```

Comment: where did you used this startGame() plesae post it here the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this dies on `showchar.setText(letArray[i]);`. That method requires a `java.lang.CharSequence`, a `char[]` or an `int resid` and you're passing in a single `char`.

---

Edit 1

Try something like this:

```
char[] tmpArray = new tmpArray[1];
tmpArray[0] = letArray[i];
```

then call:

```
showchar.setText(tmpArray);
```

Comment: Yes, I agree the mistake is in this line but I don't understand what I should do. I change the guessword to a char array and saved it to a char [] letArray. Do you mean that I cannot put a letArray in setText?

Comment: tnx for directing me to the right direction. for everyone, I found out that I still need to convert the char or the char[] to string. For this proj, I just decided to use a simple char letter(delete the char[]), use charAt(i) and then change it to string:  showchar.setText(Character.toString(letter));

Comment: @user3266210 Glad you figured it out. String implements CharSequence, so that's why that worked.